# Sending data from Android device to a Computer using UDP

Tags: java, android, network-programming, udp

I wish to send live images captured by the android device to a computer running UDP server. I wish to start this project using a simple data like String. However I am not able to send a String from an Android device to a Computer running UDP server in Netbeans.

Android Code - Client: (This code resides in the on button click listener)

```
try {
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
        byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
        sendData = "Hello Server".getBytes();

        DatagramSocket datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket();
        DatagramPacket datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, address, 2222);
        Log.i("","Client Created");

        datagramSocket.send(datagramPacket);
        Log.i("", "Datagaram Packet Sent");

    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
```

Java Code on PC - Server:

```
public class Server {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];

        DatagramSocket datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket(2222);
        DatagramPacket datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);

        datagramSocket.receive(datagramPacket);
        System.out.println("Datagram Packet Received");

        String message = new String(datagramPacket.getData());
        System.out.println(message);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: When you say that you "am not able to send a String", can you please elaborate on that? What happens when you try? Do you get exceptions, on either the sending or the receiving end? How do you create and initialize the sockets on both ends? And you do know that UDP is an unreliable protocol (if you use it you will have to count on that you will have dropped packets)?

Comment: Yes. I know UDP is an unreliable protocol. When I start the Android application and send the String, it force closes! I am trying to debug the android code, but I am not getting any messages in log. Are there any extra permissions to be added in android manifest apart from the INTERNET?